# How to detect the installed Chrome version?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I'm wondering is there a way that I can detect which version of Chrome the user is using?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? And, because Chrome is open source, you can change this to whatever you'd like before building.

Comment: Google Search (non instant) on Chrome 9 on first query uses AJAX. It's breaking my extension.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Get major version of Chrome as an integer:

```
function getChromeVersion () {     
    var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);

    return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
```

*I've updated the original answer, so that it does not throw an exception in other browsers, and does not use deprecated features.*

You can also set `minimum_chrome_version` in the manifest to not let users with older versions install it.

Comment: How would I make this an int? Need to do a comparison.. e.g `if(Version < 9)`

Comment: It is not recommended to use appVersion. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.appVersion

Comment: You need to `parseInt(raw[1])` bro, arrays start at 0.

Comment: Actually parseInt(raw[2]) is correct since match returns the full matched string at position 0.

Comment: Why not use `(?:e|ium)` instead of `(e|ium)`. Now you get an extra group cought holding either `e` or `ium`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a version, based on the answer from @serg, that extracts all of the elements of the version number:

```
function getChromeVersion () {
    var pieces = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(?:e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/);
    if (pieces == null || pieces.length != 5) {
        return undefined;
    }
    pieces = pieces.map(piece => parseInt(piece, 10));
    return {
        major: pieces[1],
        minor: pieces[2],
        build: pieces[3],
        patch: pieces[4]
    };
}
```

The naming of the elements in the object that is returned is based on [this](https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers) convention, though you can of course adapt it to be based on [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=783159#c29) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative modern solution can be just check the `navigator.userAgentData.brands`

E.g.:

```js
Boolean(navigator.userAgentData?.brands.find(({ brand, version }) => brand === 'Chromium' && parseFloat(version, 10) >= 93))
```

Comment: Update: edge also chromium, but is not support AVIF for example. So you can also search for `brand === 'Microsoft Edge'`