# complete styles for cross browser CSS zoom

Tags: css, cross-browser, zooming

I am finding it hard to get fully cross browser CSS zoom properties ..what I've is only these

```
zoom: 2;
-moz-transform: scale(2);
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

These will be sufficient for cross browser...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X4XYf/214/)

> Note: As [@martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393588/complete-styles-for-cross-browser-css-zoom/13393595#comment23603586_13393595) pointed out that *this may not work as
>   intended*, doesn't mean this fails, Chrome just makes it 2x larger
>   than other browsers, because it RESPECTS `zoom` property as well. So it makes it 2x larger...

```
zoom: 2; /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari And Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
```

HTML

```
<div class="zoom">BlahBlah</div>
```

CSS

```
.zoom {
    zoom: 2;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
    transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as expected. Modern Chrome will apply both the zoom and the scale making it 4x as large. [http://jsfiddle.net/X4XYf/148/](http://jsfiddle.net/X4XYf/148/)

Comment: @martin Any webkit ports will actually do that. `zoom` was [introduced](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) since Safari 4.

Comment: Yeah, if you can ditch IE7 and below you may be able to get away with ditching zoom and using -ms-zoom vendor prefix (it is supported in IE8+ if memory serves). With the proliferation of Webkit, I would say it would be better to not provide zoom to some random browser with market share ~0.1% and support Webkit fully.

Comment: you can also add -ms-

Comment: Should have read the comments. Yup, Chrome will double it with the use of zoom and transform.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a css only solution

```
.csszoom{
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.5); /* Opera */
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari And Chrome */
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: scale(1.5); /* Standard Property */
        transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
}
.ie8 .csszoom{
        zoom:1.5;
}
```

Change HTML tag to

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If scripting is feasible then you can avoid both the collision of multiple supported zoom properties and the browser sniffing by using future-proof feature detection.
**Note:** I'm using jQuery here for convenience, but it could be written without it.

### CSS:

```
.zoom {
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="mySelectorClass">Foobar</div>
```

### Script (One-Off Initialisation)

```
var strPropZoom = "zoom";
var blnPropZoomUseScale = false;

$(function() {
    var jqBody = $("body");

    // Determine the supported 'zoom' method
    switch (true) {
        case Boolean(jqBody.css("zoom"))              : break;
        case Boolean(jqBody.css("-moz-transform"))    : strPropNameZoom = "-moz-transform";    blnPropZoomUseScale = true; break;
        case Boolean(jqBody.css("-o-transform"))      : strPropNameZoom = "-o-transform";      blnPropZoomUseScale = true; break;
        case Boolean(jqBody.css("-webkit-transform")) : strPropNameZoom = "-webkit-transform"; blnPropZoomUseScale = true; break;
    }
})
```

Then when zooming is required simply invoke:

```
var intZoom = 2.5; // NB: This could be calculated depending on window dimensions
$(".mySelectorClass")
    .css(
        strPropZoom
        ,(blnPropZoomUseScale ? "scale(" + intZoom + ")" : intZoom)
    )
    .addClass("zoom");
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the above comment by @martin (he is correct), I created a complicated workaround using javascript (includes some jQuery) and some of @Mr. Alien's css.  Unquestionably, there are other ways to accomplish this - perhaps simpler, but, the following js and css combo works for me:

> > **css**

```
.zoom{
   -moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
   -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
   -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
   -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
   zoom:2 /*IE*/;
 }
//Notice the absence of any Webkit Transforms
```

> > **javascript**

```
(function($){
    var version=false,
    isSafari=Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0,
    isOpera=!!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0,
    isChrome=!!window.chrome && !isOpera;
    if(isChrome){
        version=(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)\./)!==null) ?
        parseInt(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)\./)[1], 10) :
        0;
        version=(version >= 10) ? true : false;
        // Don't know what version they switched it.  Figured that this was a good guess
    }
    // I added the extra ternary check in there because when testing in Chrome,
    // if I switched the user agent in the overrides section, it kept failing with 
    // null value for version.

    if(isSafari || version){
    $('.zoom').css('-webkit-transform','scale(2)');
    $('.zoom').css('-webkit-transform-origin','0 0');
        // If Scaling based upon different resolutions, a check could be included here
        // for window size, and the css could be adjusted accordingly.
    }
}(jQuery))
```

The browser detection code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) and the Chrome version detection snippet came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900436/detect-version-of-chrome-installed).

Comment: I would tend to a pure css3 transform scale, and a special stylesheet targeting IE (with conditional comments).

Comment: Yeah...That would be easier.  Not as clever, but certainly better. :)

Answer (score -3):

Seems like the answer today is

```
.zoom {
     zoom: 2; /* Chrome */
     transform: scale(2); /* FF, neglected by Chrome */
     transform-origin: 0;
}
```

That is a clinch. ;-)