# Increasing and decreasing scale of the page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created two buttons in my html code

```
<a href="#" class="increase">+</a>
<a href="#" class="decrease">-</a>
```

what i want to do is to click in the buttons and scale the page

i developed a jquery script, but it only works on chrome

```
  $(".decrease").click(function () {
        $("body").css('zoom',function (index,value) {
            if(value < 0.8){
                return value;
            } else {
                return parseFloat(value) - 0.1;
            }
        });
  });

  $(".increase").click(function () {
        $("body").css('zoom',function (index,value) {
            if(value > 1.2){
                return value;
            } else {
                return parseFloat(value) - 0.1;
            }
        });
  });
```

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: You can't really "zoom in" or "zoom out" in most common browers. All you can do is change the zoom level of your CSS, and there are many topics about it in SO.

Comment: i actually want to change the zoom property in css, but it only works on chrome

Comment: ok, this the answer, it should work !

Answer (score 1):

See here jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1totyrhj/

This variant will work in all modern browsers.

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    var currentScale = 1,
        cssPrefixesMap = [
            'scale',
            '-webkit-transform',
            '-moz-transform',
            '-ms-transform',
            '-o-transform',
            'transform'
        ];

    function setScale(scale) {
        var scaleCss = {};

        cssPrefixesMap.forEach(function (prefix) {
            scaleCss[prefix] = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
        });

        $('div').css(scaleCss);
    }

    $(".decrease").click(function () {
        setScale(currentScale = currentScale - 0.1);
    });

    $(".increase").click(function () {
        setScale(currentScale = currentScale + 0.1);
    });
})();
```

Comment: it does not look good as zoom, i tried to change $('div').css(scaleCss); to $('html').css(scaleCss); but it still doesnt look good

Comment: Of course, it doesn't. When you change it to ```html``` or ```body``` it will scale all content with your controls too.

Comment: scale() behaves different from zoom?

Comment: @user3722632 yes, you can read about this by searching "scale vs zoom". You will get many articles about this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of ways browsers handle CSS zooming, for example when doing a x2 zoom:

```
zoom: 2; /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari And Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
```

You'll need a way to handle them all. (Property list shamelessly stolen from this thread: [complete styles for cross browser CSS zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393588/complete-styles-for-cross-browser-css-zoom))

Answer (score 0):

Change your class for an ID, and then try this out :

```
    var currFFZoom = 1;
    var currIEZoom = 100;

    $('#increase').on('click',function(){
        if ($.browser.mozilla){
            if(currFFZoom < 1.2)
            {
            var step = 0.2;
            currFFZoom += step; 
            $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
            }
        } else {
            if(currIEZoom < 120)
            {
            var step = 20;
            currIEZoom += step;
            $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        }}
    });

    $('#decrease').on('click',function(){
        if ($.browser.mozilla){
             if(currFFZoom > 0.8)
            {
            var step = 0.2;
            currFFZoom -= step;                 
            $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')'); }

        } else {
            if(currIEZoom > 80)
            {
            var step = 20;
            currIEZoom -= step;
            $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT : Adapted to block after a certain amount of scale (Min/max).

Comment: i get this error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined (index):635