# Chromecast and CSS Font Loading

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I noticed that the convenient [CSS Font Loading](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-font-loading/) is available in Chrome since [version 35](http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/05/20/chrome-35-launches-developer-control-touch-input-new-apis-javascript-features/).

When can we expect the same feature on Chromecast?

According to a snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900436/detect-version-of-chrome-installed), the current version of chrome on chromecast seems to be 31.0.1650.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromecast's chrome version has been updated (v37 at the moment) and CSS Font Loading is now working properly.