# Javascript detect what Chrome version

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

What built-in Javascript/jQuery methods are there to detect what Chrome browser I'm currently using? The only method I know of currently is to type `about:version` in the URL but my Javascript is not able to simulate that command.

Comment: Can I ask what is driving this? The answers below are correct, but generally I'd recommend not relying on the browser version, but rather on feature detection.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm trying to detect for Chrome 32+ if user is able to activate Windows 8 mode for a tablet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect the installed Chrome version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900436/how-to-detect-the-installed-chrome-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `navigator.appVersion`. Related documentation can be found **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appversion.asp)**.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `navigator.userAgent`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var v = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome\/(\S+)/);
var res = v ? v[1] : 'Not a Chrome';
```

Answer (score 3):

You need navigator.appVersion:

```
//var x = navigator.appVersion;

var x = '5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2754.0 Safari/537.36';
var y = x.split('Chrome/')[1];

if( typeof y != 'undefined' ){
  y = y.split(' ')[0];
  console.log(y);
}
```

will return the chrome version: 53.0.2754.0

Comment: perfect solution :)

Answer (score 1):

To get Full version of Chrome, then Try this:

```
var v = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome\/(\S+)/);
console.log(v[0]);     // you will get: Chrome/58.0.3029.110

var r = v[0].split('/');
console.log(r[1]);          //you will get: 58.0.3029.110
```