# Detect java version in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome

I am trying to find a way to detect a user's java version using javascript.  I have tried both [PluginDetect](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect) and deployJava.js.  Both work on Firefox but return null on Chrome.  Not getting any warning about blocked plugins, and no console messages, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Anyone know?

Comment: Isnt java disabled on Chrome?

Comment: [Chrome no longer supports Java applets](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).

Comment: @RealSkeptic was just about to edit my comment to add that

Comment: check this https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  So I need some kind of Java webstart app to do this?  BTW, it doesn't work on Safari either, contra what the post on java.com says.  IDK if it's for the same reason.

Comment: @Steve May be same issue with Safari. The link is at least 3 months old. You need alternate choices to make your application cross-browser.

Comment: Safari runs Java Applets on my Mac (Yosemite - Safari 9.0.1), so I don't think it's the same problem. Also, PluginDetect seems to be working on it. Make sure you have the **JRE** installed on the Mac, as the JDK does not include a plug-in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)** or **check** also if javascript is **enable** on chrome.
But i found some sites maybe this can help u to detect browser and  browser version:

[Using jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

[2nd site](http://redsunsoft.com/2011/07/check-browser-version-in-jquery/)

[jsfiddle demo browser detect](http://sfiddle.net/oscarj24/gnenk/)

[css-trick.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-browser-and-version/)

[Javascript detect what Chrome version STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022527/javascript-detect-what-chrome-version)

[And This last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339480/how-to-detect-if-a-browser-is-chrome-using-jquery)

Comment: How are these links helpful?

Comment: detecting browser and browser version

Comment: And why is this helpful when the question was specifically about detecting Java in a browser that's known to be Chrome?

Comment: Whats up with the jsfiddle demo browser detect? bad link? look like it tried to open up a virus

Comment: oo  i am sorry i dont know what happen

Comment: Can't you do that with document.write(window.navigator.userAgent)?

Comment: @Phoenix You should edit your post based on the comments from others

Comment: Doing UA detection is a terrible way of determining that Java isn't present; the original question is already doing plugin detection that shows that Java isn't there, so using UA is not necessary.