# Can I get the Command line information using Javascript? It is not the browser version information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I type url   chrome://version in chrome browser
and I can see command line information.

Can I get the **command line** information? NOT the browser version but the command line information such as

**Command Line  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end**

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect version of chrome installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900436/detect-version-of-chrome-installed)

Comment: It is not the version of browser but the command line information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the user agent you can follow the advices on this answer [Getting the User Agent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450066/getting-the-user-agent-with-javascript)